# MDX query to pivot table based on condition

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

I'm trying to write MDX query for pivot table.

Similar query in RDBMS is like this:

```
SELECT  stats_Date
        ,ISNULL(SUM(clicks), 0) AS clicks
        ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ad_type IN (1,3) THEN clicks END), 0) AS keyword_clicks
        ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ad_type IN (2,3) THEN clicks END), 0) AS direct_clicks
FROM    STATS_TABLE (NOLOCK)
WHERE   stats_Date BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-30'
GROUP BY stats_Date
```

I've two dimensions `[DIM TIME]` & `[DIM AD TYPE]`

I've tried below MDX query for this:

```
WITH    
    MEMBER [Measures].[Clicks Keyword] AS     
        IIF
        (
          [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].CurrentMember IS [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[1]
         ,[Measures].[clicks]
         ,0
        )
SELECT  {
          [Measures].[Clicks]
         ,[Measures].[Clicks Keyword]
        } ON COLUMNS
        ,{ 
          [DIM TIME].[CalendarHierarchy].[Date]*[DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].[Ad Type]
        }  ON ROWS
FROM    [CM_STATS_CUBE]
WHERE   ([DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506]:[DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506]})
```

Sample output of this MDX query looks like this:

```
                       Clicks       Clicks Keyword
20150501    Invalid    (null)       0             
20150501    unknown    200          0
20150501    Keyword    500          0
20150501    Ads        300          300
20150502    Invalid    (null)       0
20150502    unknown    400          0
20150502    Keyword    600          0
20150502    Ads        500          500
```

but I want to only group by stats_date and the expected output is:

```
            Clicks      Clicks Keyword
20150501    1000        300
20150502    1500        500
```

Similar example for testing in [Adventure Works] cube database:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US] AS  
    IIF( [Customer].[Customer Geography].CurrentMember IS [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
         ,NULL
       )
SELECT {
         [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US]
       } ON 0
       ,NON EMPTY{[Date].[Calendar].[Date]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE   {[Date].[Date].&[20050701]:[Date].[Date].&[20050702]}
```

Comment: That example is no good. It gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to bother with the cross-join `[DIM TIME].[CalendarHierarchy].[Date]*[DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].[Ad Type]`

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Clicks Keyword] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].CurrentMember IS [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[1]
     ,[Measures].[clicks]
     ,0
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Clicks]
   ,[Measures].[Clicks Keyword]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{[DIM TIME].[CalendarHierarchy].[Date]} ON ROWS
FROM [CM_STATS_CUBE]
WHERE 
  [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506] : [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506];
```

Also I would suggest using `null` rather than `0` in your `IIF` function - this should tidy up the result and speed things up:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Clicks Keyword] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].CurrentMember IS [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[1]
     ,[Measures].[clicks]
     ,null   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< better to use null rather than 0
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Clicks]
   ,[Measures].[Clicks Keyword]
  } ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< now if Clicks and Clicks Keyword are both null the respective row will be excluded
  {[DIM TIME].[CalendarHierarchy].[Date]} ON ROWS
FROM [CM_STATS_CUBE]
WHERE 
  [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506] : [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506];
```

---

**Edit**

I'd not read your script in enough detail - apologies. You can just just aggregate a set of two tuples:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Clicks Keyword] AS 
    Sum
    (
     {
      ([DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[1],[Measures].[clicks])
     ,([DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[3],[Measures].[clicks])
     }
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Clicks]
   ,[Measures].[Clicks Keyword]
  } ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< now if Clicks and Clicks Keyword are both null the respective row will be excluded
  {[DIM TIME].[CalendarHierarchy].[Date]} ON ROWS
FROM [CM_STATS_CUBE]
WHERE 
  [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506] : [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506];
```

The `AdvWrks` example you posted would just be a single tuple:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US] AS  
      (
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
SELECT {
         [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US]
       } ON 0
       ,NON EMPTY{[Date].[Calendar].[Date]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE   {[Date].[Date].&[20050701]:[Date].[Date].&[20050702]}
```

If you wanted to add in Canada then there seem to be three viable alternatives:

1.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US & Canada] AS  
      (
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    +
      (
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Canada]
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
```

2.

```
 WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US & Canada] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
       ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Canada]
      }
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    )
```

3.
(Switch to Sum)

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount US & Canada] AS 
    Sum
    (
      {
        (
          [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Canada]
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
       ,(
          [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
      }
    )
```

Comment: thanks.. but I've tried this and there are all zeros or nulls in the output column.

Comment: Can some one please try and show a similar query on `[Adventure Works]` test database?

Comment: @Omesh Please make the change I suggested to your calculated member `[Measures].[Clicks Keyword]` i.e. have `null` as one of the branches. Then also note I have added the key words `NON EMPTY` to your `ON ROWS` statement

Comment: tried this also but still no luck. I've edited question for similar example in `[Adventure Works]` database. You can test the output of this query on this.

Comment: How will the `[DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].CurrentMember` work? There is no scope set.

Comment: good point sourav - I'd not actually noticed that part of the calculated member's definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Clicks Keyword] AS 
  AGGREGATE({[DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[1], [DIM AD TYPE].[Ad Type].&[3]}, [Measures].[Clicks])

SELECT NON EMPTY
  {
    [Measures].[Clicks]
   ,[Measures].[Clicks Keyword]
  } ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY  
  {[DIM TIME].[CalendarHierarchy].[Date]} ON ROWS
FROM [CM_STATS_CUBE]
WHERE 
  ([DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506] : [DIM TIME].[Month].&[201506]);
```

Comment: how can we include this condition `ad_type IN (1,3)`

Comment: Thanks! Tried this also but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is the issue with it?